# How to automatically restore Exchanges in Rabbitmq after it is deleted unexpected

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, recovery

How to automatically restore Exchanges in Rabbitmq after it is deleted unexpected(from client).
I'm using spring amqp in my project, but i don't know how to active this feature, i can't even catch a exception when the Exchange disappear. So is there any way to do this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would disable delete permission for clients of the broker since removal of that exchange is not your logic, but you definitely can try to use Broker Events to catch such a change and react to it respectively via `RabbitAdmin` API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-events

Comment: In fact, in my scenario, the disappearance of the exchange might be caused by a RabbitMQ broker failure, so I can re-declare the exchange by periodically calling RabbitAdmin#initialize.